# using variable as regex substitution parameter

Tags: perl

I've been doing some searching and haven't found an answer. Why isn't this working?

```
    $self->{W_CONTENT} =~ /$regex/;
    print $1; #is there a value? YES
    $store{URL} =~ s/$param/$1/;
```

Yes $1 has a value. $param is replaced however it is replaced with nothing. I'm positive $1 has a value. If I replace with text instead of "$1" it works fine. Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `$1` to have a value you need to ensure that `$param` has parentheses `()` in it. i.e. The following has a problem similar to what you are explaining.

```
my $fred = "Fred";
$fred =~ s/red/$1/;
# $fred will now be "F"
```

But this works

```
my $fred = "Fred";
$fred =~ s/r(ed)/$1/;
# $fred will now be "Fed"
```

Now if you want to use the `$1` from your first regex in the second one you need to copy it. Every regex evaluation resets `$1` ... `$&`. So you want something like:

```
$self->{W_CONTENT} =~ /$regex/;
print $1; #is there a value? YES
my $old1 = $1;
$store{URL} =~ s/$param/$old1/;
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked great. I was playing around with the brackets but I did not think that $1 was reset. Tricky!

Comment: You might consider `s/\Q$param\E/$old1/` if there is any chance that `$param` will contain meta characters.

Answer (score 1):

Backreferences such as $1 shouldn't be used inside the expression; you'd use a different notation - for an overview, check out [Perl Regular Expressions Quickstart](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html).

Consider getting the value of $1 and storing it in another variable, *then* using that in the regex.